# Can't update text area in swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, network-programming

this is my first question on StackOverflow, so I hope my question is not too vague or in the wrong format.

I am trying to build a desktop chatting application in Java with a GUI built in Swing using the Netbeans Swing GUI builder. There is one server hosting the chat while multiple clients can connect and leave the chat. For each client that connects to the server, I create a new thread to handle all communication with that respective client. When a client sends a message, it first goes to the server where a thread reads it, updates the chat log(the textarea) and then writes the message onto all the other clients by calling write().

The following is the server code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class server extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable
{

    static Socket sock[]=new Socket[100];                       //Array of sockets, 1 for each accept
    static server obj[]=new server[100];                        //Array of server objects, 1 for each thread
    static Thread threads[]=new Thread[100];                    //Array of threads, 1 for each client
    static boolean conn_state[]=new boolean[100];               //Array of boolean values depicting whether connection is closed or not
    static DataOutputStream dos[]=new DataOutputStream[100];    //Array of DataOutputStreams, 1 for each client
    static InetAddress ipaddr[]=new InetAddress[100];           //Array to hold InetAddress objects of each client
    static int port[]=new int[100];                             //Array to hold port numbers
    static int i=0;                                             //No. of clients
    static int except=0;                                        //Marks client no. who sent last message
    static int count=0;                                         //Total no. of open connections at any time
    static boolean flag=false;                                  //Currently unused
    static String str;                                          //To hold message sent by a client
    public server() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setText("Chat Log :");

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        jButton1.setText("Stop Server");
        jButton1.setToolTipText("Stop the server hosting the chat.");
        jButton1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(120, 25));

        jButton2.setText("Print Chat Log");
        jButton2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(120, 25));

        jScrollPane1.setAutoscrolls(true);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new 
 javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(52, 52, 52)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(52, 52, 52))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 356, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(34, 34, 34))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void serve()
    {
        System.out.println("Server Program Running");
        try
        {
            ServerSocket ss =new ServerSocket(50000);
            while(true)
            {
                sock[i]=ss.accept();        
                System.out.println("Client with IP Address :- "+sock[i].getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+sock[i].getPort()+" connected.");
                obj[i]=new server();
                threads[i]=new Thread(obj[i]);
                conn_state[i]=true;
                dos[i]=new DataOutputStream(sock[i].getOutputStream());
                ipaddr[i]=sock[i].getInetAddress();
                port[i]=sock[i].getPort();
                count++;
                i++;
                threads[i-1].start();   //A new thread is created for each client to read all incoming messages and write it out to every other client
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            int k=i-1;  //Marks client no.

            //TextArea does not get updated by the following lines
            jTextArea1.append("Client with IP Address :- "+sock[k].getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+sock[k].getPort()+" connected.");
            jTextArea1.update(jTextArea1.getGraphics());

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(sock[k].getInputStream());
            while(true)
            {
                //System.out.println("k="+k);
                str=dis.readUTF();
                if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                {
                    //If a client types exit, the server closes all socket and streams of that client and writes out thst the client has left
                    dis.close();
                    conn_state[k]=false;
                    sock[k].close();
                    count--;
                    str="Client with ip ="+(ipaddr[k].getHostAddress())+" and port no. = "+port[k]+" left the chat.";
                    flag=true;
                    write();
                    if(count!=0)       //When open connections = 0, the server shuts down
                    return;
                    else
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                except=k;
                str=ipaddr[k].getHostAddress()+":"+port[k]+" :- "+str;
                System.out.println(str);

                //The text area does not get updated
                jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+str);
                jTextArea1.repaint();

                write();    //Function to write out "str" to all other clients
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void write()
    {
        int c;
        for(c=0;c<i;c++)
        {
            //System.out.println(c);
            if(c==except||conn_state[c]==false)     //If c=current sender's client no. or connection is closed then do not write to it
                continue;
            try
            {
                /*if(!flag)
                    str="From IP Address :- "+ipaddr[except].getHostAddress()+":"+port[except]+"\nMessage : "+str;*/
                dos[c].writeUTF(str);           //Writing "str" to every client other than except
                dos[c].flush();
                //dos.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new server().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    serve();    //Main job done by server
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Now when I connect to the server as a client, the "client has connected" message and all the messages that the client sends are properly output to the console but nothing appears in the text area. The client code only consists of connecting to the server and then running 2 threads, one for reading and one for writing.

When I had implemented this many client-server model in C, without any GUI it had worked fine. I had even managed to make the same work in Java when all outputs were printed onto the console and not to a GUI. When I try to include a GUI, then nothing shows up on the GUI. A google search of my problems led to questions on StackOverflow from which I have come to understand that Swing Components can be altered only by 1 thread called EDT and no other thread can alter them. They recommended using

```
SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    JTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+str);
    }
});
```

but I have tried this and it still does not work.

I would be much obliged if you would kindly look into the matter. I am very sorry if the code was too clustered, unclean or full of bad practices. I am still new to coding and even newer to Java, and any feedback is welcome.

Comment: You create a new `server` instance for each client that connects.That means that you also create a new `JFrame` with an empty `JTextArea` for each client. You will only see the textarea of the last connecting client.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thank you. I need to create a new instance for creation of every thread, so should I create a inner class for the threads while the main class only has 1 instance for the GUI? Also, if I only have 1 client connected to the server then shouldn't its messages appear in the textarea as this is the only textarea up right now? Because I have done that but still nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my first analysis was not complete.

The `JFrame` that you see is the one created within the `main` method. There is however no thread that ever writes something into it's textarea, since you do not keep a reference to either the frame or to the textarea.

Every further `server` instance that you create will create it's on `JFrame` and `JTextArea`, but these will never be shown on screen (you never call `setVisible(true);` on these frames).

To solve your problem it would be better to create two classes:

- one for communicating with the client (it's ok to create instances of this class for every client that connects, maybe call this `ServerCommunication`)
- one for the GUI of the application (you will only have one instance of this class an pass a reference to it to every communication class instance, maybe call this `ServerGUI`)

---

The correct way to update the textarea is from the fragment that you provided:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+str);
    }
});
```

or, with the lambdas from Java 8 and later:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+str);
});
```

Please do not try to call `jTextArea1.repaint();` or `jTextArea1.update(jTextArea1.getGraphics());` - in this context these calls are nonsense and completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. By making two classes it finally worked like a charm.